# Archive old data in Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, archive

I use a Sharpoint file which acts as a master file with a lot of data in it (>180K rows). I have other teams who use this data and have dependencies on it. What is the best way to move some this data to another place to make process of pasting or filtering data faster? I need to be able to provide data that I move when needed and provide LTD numbers based on it. If I split the files then how do I provide LTD numbers or do other data analysis?

Comment: Filter so you work on a subset - quicker for you. But as you seem to imply all the data needs to be available not sure what else you expect.

Comment: Adding more context. I was thinking of splitting the master in two files and use excel formulas across workbooks to provide LTD numbers. However I found out it is not possible on Sharepoint. As a workaround I would split the files in 2. File 1 would be for older data with static numbers. File 2, I can keep live and add on to the static numbers from File 1. File 2 can be then used by other teams for daily updates. Just wanted to check if there is a better way to do this.